# Android Media Controller hides when loses focus

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I'm using a media controller associated with a media player to play a sound. The issue is that the media controller is hiding as soon as it loses focus. I have a button which when pressed, the sound is played and the media controller shows up at the bottom of the screen.

But when life pause is pressed, after like 5 seconds, the media controller itself hides.

here are part of my codes. I'm stopping the media player as soon as the media controller hides so that the sound is not continually played

All the codes for the media controller are:

```
     mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                            mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(currentFragment);

                            mediaController = new MediaController(getActivity()){
                                @Override
                                public void hide()
                                {

                                    if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
                                        mediaPlayer.stop(); 
                                    }
                                    super.hide();
                                }
                            };


                              try {
                                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(sound.getSound());
                                 mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
                            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } catch (SecurityException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                              mediaPlayer.start();


    @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                Log.d("media status", "onPrepared");



                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                  public void run() {

                      launchMediaController();
                      progress.dismiss();
                  }
                });

            }



void launchMediaController(){
            mediaController.setEnabled(true);

            mediaPlayer.start();
            mediaController.setMediaPlayer(soundController);
            mediaController.setAnchorView(getView());
            mediaController.show(0);
        }

        private class SoundController implements MediaController.MediaPlayerControl{

            public void start() {
                mediaPlayer.start();
              }

              public void pause() {
                mediaPlayer.pause();
              }

              public int getDuration() {
                return mediaPlayer.getDuration();
              }

              public int getCurrentPosition() {
                return mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
              }

              public void seekTo(int i) {
                mediaPlayer.seekTo(i);
              }

              public boolean isPlaying() {
                return mediaPlayer.isPlaying();
              }

              public int getBufferPercentage() {
                return 0;
              }

              public boolean canPause() {
                return true;
              }

              public boolean canSeekBackward() {
                return true;
              }

              public boolean canSeekForward() {
                return true;
              }

            @Override
            public int getAudioSessionId() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return 0;
            }   
      }
```

**Edits:**
Based on the answer of Libin, I did the following with no success:
**Extends MediaController and overrides touch event**

```
private class MyMediaController extends MediaController{

            public MyMediaController(Context context) {
                super(context);
                // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            }
            @Override
            public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
                return true;
            }
        }
```

**Use extended class**

```
mediaController = new MyMediaController(getActivity()){
                            @Override
                            public void hide()
                            {

                                if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
                                    mediaPlayer.stop(); 
                                }
                                super.hide();
                            }
                        };
```

launchMediaController() is actually what launches the media controller.
My question, why does the media controller hides by itself after some seconds after the user touches it? Is there any solution to this?

Answer (score 3):

when you call show() , you can set a duration to show the controller on screen. so the controller will automatically hide after 'timeout' milliseconds of inactivity.

You can set the timeout as 0 , to show the controller until the hide is explicitly called.

```
   controller.show(0);
```

***Use 0 to show the controller until hide() is called.***

If you use show() method without argument , the default timeout is 3 seconds

*Here is some code from **show(int timeOut)** method call*

```
 Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(FADE_OUT);
    if (timeout != 0) {
        mHandler.removeMessages(FADE_OUT);
        mHandler.sendMessageDelayed(msg, timeout);
    }
```

The handler is send a delayed message if the timeout id not 0, and in handler if the message is FADE_OUT the hide method is called

**EDIT**

There is bug in MediaController code. In the onTouchEvent the default timeout is set , which will override the timeout 0.

```
  @Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    show(sDefaultTimeout);
    return true;
}
```

**You can fix this by creating a custom MediaController and override the onTouchEvent**

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    return true;
}
```

Comment: this is what i'm doing, but it is hiding some seconds after the user touches it

Comment: I've added the code I use to display the media controller

Comment: see my answer. create a custom MediaContoller and override the onTouchEvent()

Comment: What you did is very logical, yet its not working, i've updated the question with the suggestion you told

Comment: Ok, It seems Mediacontoller has a onTouch listener for window decor view, which calls the hide. We need to find some way to disable that. let you know if I can create a sample on this

Comment: ok, i'll be trying as well, and put any updates on this question, thanks !!

Comment: Was a solution found for this?